# Running two different test files sequentially in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have two test files with their own describe blocks. Within each describe block there is before block which manipulates mongoose schema (shared by both the files). Is there a way to sequentially run these two test files so that "before" of one file doesn't block test of another file.

Comment: You shouldn't make independent tests rely on other tests. Instead you could `require` a test harness in each where the result of the `require` is cached and only ran once.

Comment: @Kevin, I might have not been to explain what I am trying to do. I am writing test cases for model and controller (in different files) and both test are using schema which gets populated using MongoDB. Since before test I do a data clean up. I don't want test to fail because data was cleaned up by other parallel running test